# Javascript IMG Insert

Tags: javascript, html, image, dom

```
im_bar = document.createElement("img");
im_bar.id = UPDATE_STATUS_RESPONSE[0]+"_SPLIT";
im_bar.style.display = "block";
im_bar.style.margin = "0px auto 0px auto";
im_bar.src = "graphics/news_feed_line.png";
document.getElementById("SCRIPT_NEWS_FEEDS").insertBefore(im_bar,document.getElementById("SCRIPT_NEWS_FEEDS").firstChild);
```

Produces

```
<img src="graphics/news_feed_line.png" style="display: block; margin: 11px auto 0px;" id="2_SPLIT">
```

**Question**: Why doesn't the outputted margin match what I define in javascript?

Comment: Cool story, bro.

Comment: hmm..is that what you are seeing in the live html (from like firebug)? Are you sure it's not inheriting that 11px from something else, after you insert it?

Comment: yes. not sure. but I'm using Firefox 4 so my firebug doesnt work :(

Comment: @Shane - upgrade Firebug to 1.7.0, it should work fine with Firefox 4

Comment: if im setting the margin, why would it change the margins?

Comment: The "id" values of elements should not start with digits - they should look (more or less) like valid identifiers.

Comment: true, thanks for the tip, but does anyone know why the top margin is set to 11px?

Comment: lmao found my problem, I changed it down the road by mistake. Thanks Russ for the tip i missed firebug so much lol

Comment: @Pointy - I think the HTML5 spec recommendation is a lot more relaxed about ids now. IIRC, it says that they just need to be at least one character.

Comment: @Russ Cam that would be nice, but doesn't IE in particular get weird about bad "id" values?  It's one of those things that I know almost as "folk wisdom", so of course I don't experiment very often to see what actually happens :-)

Comment: @Pointy - I think older versions of IE < 6 do, i just tried a very simple demo with IE6 and it seemed ok (it just returned values for the first element with the given id), but it may break down in more complex scenarios. The HTML 5 recommendation is here http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigning all these styles in javascript, you should use a css class.

Comment: i didnt think of that lol, but what is causing the problem?